# How to get Recomposition count when using compose inside composeview?

Tags: android, layout, android-jetpack-compose

I am using compose function inside compose view. How to get the recomposition count in the layout inspector(it is not shown detailed)?

How to get layout three and the recomposition count when using compose functions inside compose view in XML?